# Ignoring subfolder in URI

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with .htaccess configuration.
I know how to ignore file extensions (e.g. php).
That's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But I want to ignore specific a subfolder in the URI.
For example, I have a file in `example.com/sites/test.php` but in the address bar, I just want to type `example.com/test`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /sites/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have one more question. Can you tell me how to give forbidden access to some specified files on site?

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule ^blockme/?$ - [F]` rule

Answer (score 1):

You can change the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/$1.php
```